# nginx + uwsgi + django "could not import settings"

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

Ok I must be so stupid but I cannot figure out how to get this working, I have nearly two hours and I cannot advance anymore and I honestly don't know what's wrong, I've read a lot of guides and I am doing everything fine..

But let's paste you the configs:

dir struct:

```
├── apps
├── config
    └── wsgi.py
    ├── settings.py
├── dev
├── env
├── static
│   ├── css
│   ├── img
│   └── js
│       └── vendor
└── templates
    ├── admin
    │   └── supervisor
    └── base
├── manage.py
```

wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys

from site import addsitedir
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join

sys.path.insert(0, abspath(join(dirname(__file__), "..")))
sys.path.insert(0, abspath(join(dirname(__file__), "../apps")))
sys.path.insert(1, abspath(join(dirname(__file__), "../config")))

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

backoffice.ini

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /var/www/backoffice
mountpoint = /var/www/backoffice
gid = www-data
uid = www-data
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.backoffice.sock
virtualenv = /var/www/backoffice/env
plugins = python
master = True
chmod-socket = 666
memory-report = 1
harakiri = 20
processes = 4
profiler = 1
pythonpath = /var/www/backoffice
vacuum = True
max-requests = 5000
```

Then I run the following command:

```
uwsgi --ini /var/www/backoffice/backoffice.ini -b 32000 --wsgi-file /var/www/backoffice /config/wsgi.py
```

And I get the error of "could not import settings it is on sys.path" of course it is!!

sys.path

```
['/var/www/backoffice/', '.', '', '/var/www/backoffice/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg', '/var/www/backoffice/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg', '/var/www/backoffice/env/src/django-logicaldelete', '/var/www/backoffice/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg', '/var/www/backoffice/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg', '/var/www/backoffice/env/lib/python2.7', '/var/www/backoffice/env/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu', '/var/www/backoffice/env/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/var/www/backoffice/env/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/var/www/backoffice/env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/var/www/backoffice/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/var/www/backoffice/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Any hint? what's too obvious that I'm not seeing.. Thanks

Comment: Can you `import config.settings` from a Python shell, with the virtualenv activated?

Comment: Yep when I run python manage.py shell on the virtualenv and import config.settings everything works

Comment: Even if you are outside of `/var/www/backoffice/`?

Comment: Yep I run:

    python /var/www/backoffice/manage.py shell

And then:

    import config.settings

And works fine.

Comment: How did you get the `sys.path` from the end of your question? It doesn't look like your changes via `sys.path.insert` (apps, config) are in there—did you `print sys.path` in your wsgi file, or something else?

Comment: Yes I did print the sys.path on the wsgi file and that's the result.

Comment: What's that second space in "--wsgi-file /var/www/backoffice /config/wsgi.py"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked again and @sk1p pointed out that I might be have issues on my settings which was true after debugging deep, I was importing the translation library and that made a circular import issue.

Thanks for the help man